# Expect script called from bash script not returning control when completed

Tags: bash, expect

I am calling the expect script from bash script inside for loop using multithreading in it. The expect script does ssh login and call python script using nohup command for restarting host.
But, after completing the restart, the control not returned to the bash script.

Shell script code:

```
for host in ${hosts[@]};
do
  ./b.exp $id $pswd $host &
done
wait
echo "Completed"
```

Expect script code:

```
set timeout -1
spawn ssh <server login>
send "nohup /loc/c.py $host\r"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

I am expecting after all the hosts restart completion, the script should print "Completed".
But, it is not printing anything and I need to manually exit the execution.

Could someone please tell what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 0):

`nohup` doesn't detach the terminal, you want to send

```
 nohup /loc/c.py $host &
```

where the `&` to run the job in the background is the significant change.

(Properly speaking `$host` should be quoted, too, but if you are sure it contains a single token without whitespace or wildcard characters, this should not matter. Similarly `"${hosts[@]}"` should have double quotes, but again, under the given conditions, this should be fine without quotes.)